# Display iPhone/iPad/iPod on PC screen

Tags: mac, iphone, display, ipod, ipad

I was wondering, is it possible to display the iPhone's screen on your Mac? So if you want to give a presentation about what you can do with an app, and you connect your iPhone/iPad/iPod to your Mac, and connect your Mac to a projection screen?

I have read about iDemo (demoGod) but I don't have a jailbroken one. I was wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad2 has a mirror mode, where you install a dongle and it outputs the screen contents to both the iPad2 screen and whatever output device is connected to the dongle.
[link to HDMI dongle](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE&mco=MTcyMTgxNTk)

Kind of a pricey way to do projection though....

Answer (score 1):

just found another airplay receiver, [lonelyscreen](http://www.lonelyscreen.com)

mirroring works with iOS 9.2. but youtube playback doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

LiveView Screencaster in the iOS app store.  Pretty simple but it does the job.

Comment: When I go to the app store it doesn't give any results on 'Lineview', and neither on Screencaster. How can I find this on the app store?

Comment: Oh liVeView, my bad, read it wrong!

Comment: I just downloaded it, but it views the MAC screen on my device, how do i show the device's screen on my MAC?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

that would let you hook it right up to the projector, if the Mac intermediary isn't REQUIRED.

edit:changed link based on recommendation of someone who just did that a few days ago...there was a weird little bug where the video out would just push one frame and then go static, but if you (while already cabled up) went to the youtube app, and then back to yours, it would stream live [but would NOT output video camera capture (so no demoing AR)]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the already mentioned AirServer, there is another paid OSX app for that: [Reflections.app](http://www.reflectionapp.com/)

It only works with the iPhone 4S and iPad 2 (and presumably the new iPad just released).

With this application there is no need to jailbreak or install any app on the iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that you can use QuickTime's recording mode to see your iPhone/iPod scren on your Mac. You open QuickTime > Files > New Recording and then select your device. You actually don't even need to start recording to see it.

I personally haven't tried it, and probably is not gonna look really fancy while you present it (maybe unless you record it and present it as a video, instead of a live-interactive presentation) but it certainly may do the trick and get you out of the hurry